# Rails 4: How to access database in SCSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

I have implemented a CarrierWave Uploader into my Rails Project. Now I want to set the uploaded file as background within my SCSS File.

That way I access the image in haml:

```
= image_tag @item.cover_filename.url
```

And this is my SCSS:

```
#head {
    background-image: url('cover.png'); /* change this from my current placeholder to the uploaded file. */
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help! Please tell me if you need additional information.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible as far as I know to have your SCSS file access dynamic data like models, current_user information, etc, you can really only render static ruby code.

That said you could add some code to your layout file, or create a custom one for these pages, that checks to see if the item has uploaded a custom image and change it there, with inline styling/CSS.

Something like:

```
<% if @item.cover_filename.url.exists? %>
  <body style="background-image: url('<%= @item.cover_filename.url) %>');">
<% else %>
  <body>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! How am I able to do that within haml? This does not work: `#head{:style => "background-image: url('cover.png');"}`

Comment: I don't use HAML but it looks like you are setting a style tag on the header element, which isn't right. My example set an inline style on the body tag. Also you may need to use !important on the inline style in order to get it to override your default style.

Comment: Hmm.. This is nod an header element, just a div I gave that id to. I have removed that default state from my css, so currently I get just a whit background.

Comment: I fixed it by implementing it as `image_tag` and styled it to look like a background. Thanks for your help :)